# Will having a new site affect my pageviews on websiteoutlook.com

Tags: seo

I am planning on launching a new version of my current company website.
I have a lot of pageviews (measured through websiteoutlook.com).
Will having the new site (with new pages) affect the pageviews, and therefore my search engine ranking?

If yes, what can I do to preserve my search engine ranking?
Thanks!

Comment: Page views do not affect search engine rankings

Answer (score 1):

> Will having the new site (with new pages) affect the pageviews, and therefore my search engine ranking?

That question is the wrong way around. Your pageviews will not affect your SER, but your SER may affect your pageviews.

It will very probably affect it. The question is probably: How much?

You definitely want to check how many people visit your website through search engines.

SEO may improve or worsen, depending on how you do your relaunch. The most important things:

- Optimize your new site for SEO. (maybe speaking URLs, proper headlines and markup, keywords, etc etc)
- Try to keep your URLs to point to the updated content, and/or make them redirect to the updated content. If you had `/content/about` and now want to use `/about`, make that `/content/about` now redirects to `/about` with the proper HTML status code.